# When is the PropertyChangedCallback fired

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, windows-8, dependency-properties

I have trouble understanding a problem that occured to me.

I Have a UserControl that is structured somwhat like this.

```cs
public class SomePage : Page
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(IPropertyValue), typeof(SomeControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomePropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnSomePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Some Stuff
    }
}
```

And a ViewModel that looks like this

```cs
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IPropertyValue _prop;
    public IPropertyValue Property
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_prop== null)
                _prop = new SomeConcreteValue();
            return _prop;
        }
    }
}
```

And the whole Stuff is bound to a Page

```xml
<common:LayoutAwarePage>
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:SomeViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <ctrl:SomePage SomeProperty="{Binding Property}" />
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

In my understanding the PropertyChangedCallbacked is called whenever the Value of the DependencyProperty changes.

Allthough the value of ViewModel.Property does never change, the value of the DependencyProperty "SomeProperty" still does, as it changes from null to the inital bound value.

Is there any other possibility to get notified once the Property is initialized or am I simply missing something here?

**Edit**:
Maybe I was not clear about this. My problem is that the PropertyCahngedCallback is not fired when the initial value is set to SomeProperty.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've edited the question. I need to get notified when the inital value is set to the _SomeProperty_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I did'nt look at the log very closely. 
The problem was'nt that the event i'nt fired but in fact that the Binding i'nt possible.
It seems that in Windows 8 Store Apps DependencyProperties with interface Types don't work as expected:

```
Error: Converter failed to convert value of type '#Namespace.ConcretePropertyType#, #Application#, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' to type 'IPropertyValue'; BindingExpression: Path='Property' DataItem=''Namespace.SomeViewModel, #Application#, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is '#Namespace.ConcretePropertyType#' (Name='null'); target property is '#ConcretePropertyType#' (type 'IPropertyValue').
```

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/5ec0a4ba-b80a-4a8a-8e5a-f2fe776c45b5/